# How many counts of mantra is permissable after 108 chants?

Tags: mantras, puja, vedic-chanting

Usually 108 chants is done if we don’t have time to do 1008 how much is permissible in 200’s - 900’s.

Comment: 108 or  it's multiples .. so two malas (216), three malas or any number you are comfortable with unless there is a specific requirement for that particular Japa like 5 malas or 10 malas etc.

Comment: Usual japa counts are 10, 28, 108, 1008